# Same class name for multiple elements but execute event independently in pure jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hello guys I want to know if there is a way were I can press on a targeted button which will only affect that button only regardless if they have the same class name and I don't want to press on a targeted

button and that event that is attach to that class name is executed on all of them I only want to execute an event for that targeted button independently on each of them not on all of them by one button. I was wondering how I can do this in jQuery

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.x').click(function(){
  $('.x').css({'background-color': 'red'})
});
}); 
</script>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
```

Comment: Yes, target the element you get the event for, not all elements with the class set. In plain JavaScript you get the event as a parameter to the callback.

Comment: Well I did this as a simple example on here so you guys know what I mean not to do a show off  long complicated code example.. do you know how to do this Sami Kuhmonen :-) in a code example I been trying to figure this out for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.x').click(function(){
  $(this).css({'background-color': 'red'})
});
}); 
</script>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
```

Comment: Never mine about the JavaScript question I put that in another post to make it easier but thank you for your help @Patel Akshay I thought I would have to use a loop or something but thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use this in click event. This will refer to the current class on which you click. Below is the code snippet:-

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.x').click(function(){
  $(this).css({'background-color': 'red'})
});
}); 
</script>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
```