# Similar class name for multiple elements but execute event independently in pure plain JS

Tags: javascript, html

Is there is a way were I can press on a targeted button which will only affect that button only regardless if they have the same class name and I don't want to press on a targeted

button and that event that is attach to that class name is executed on all of them I only want to execute an event for that targeted button independently on each of them not on all of them by one button. I was wondering how I can do this **in pure plain Javascript.**

This is my code

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var allButtons= document.getElementsByClassName('x');
    
  for(var i= 0; i< allButtons.length; i++){
allButtons[i].addEventListener('click', fx);
  }
    
    function fx(){
      for(var i1= 0; i1< allButtons.length; i1++){
        allButtons[i1].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      }
    }
    
  });
</script>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
```

Comment: Well that's why I cam on here I don't know how to do this I just need help on how I can do this in pure plain JavaScript well I asked this for pure jquery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48838591/same-class-name-for-multiple-elements-but-execute-event-independently-in-pure-jq  Now I want to know how I can do this in pure plain Javascript  now do you know how to this in a code example @Teemu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Using `this` as the current target.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var allButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('x');
  var len = allButtons.length;
  while(len--) {
    allButtons[len].onclick = function() {
       this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect the clicked element (target element) instead of looping through the all buttons and applying the style.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var allButtons= document.getElementsByClassName('x');

  for(var i= 0; i< allButtons.length; i++){
    allButtons[i].addEventListener('click', fx);
  }
  //e refer the element that is clicked
  function fx(e){
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }

});
```

```html
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much every one but I got to give this best answer rate to @CodeLover I actually liked your first code example. But you changed it... I know you did this to help me out better and I appreciate that but your first code example from earlier fits my style.

```html
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var allButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('x'); 
  for(var i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++){
    allButtons[i].addEventListener('click', fx);
  }
  function fx(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
}); 
</script>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
<button class='x'>Execute</button>
```

But thanks for the solution @CodeLover.